# Can I replicate iOS Safari on OS Safari?

Tags: ios, safari

I have an HTML animation created using Adobe Edge Animate that plays fine in my desktop browser version of Safari (9.0.1)

It doesn't work on the iPad platform it is targeted at, and it transpires that some of the image names in the assets folder are not capitalised. The HTML is calling for 'pasted.svg' for example and the file is called 'Pasted.svg'

OS Safari seems to be using some kind of fuzzy logic to be kind to the developer and is working out which image to use. iOS is not, which doesnt help me bugtest.

Is there a way I can duplicate this behaviour on OS Safari so I dont need to keep loading up to the iPad to test if the animations will work?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the iOS simulator if you have it.